# Powershell Switch Condition

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having a little trouble with a PS script right now.

**What I am trying to do:**

Depending on which OU a computer belongs to, it should get a different printer mapped.

I am trying this with a switch condition, but regardless of what I try the condition seems to be always TRUE (although I know it isn't)

When I type in the condition into PowerShell manually, I get the correct values if the condition is TRUE or FALSE. But as soon as I use it in the switch, the condition seems to be always TRUE.

**What I have so far:**

With `dsquery` I check if a computer belongs to a specific OU.
If a value is returned, which only happens if the query succeeds, I put it into my $SwitchDump variable (Condition TRUE).

From my understanding, if a device is not found in the OU, there is no value that will be passed to my $SwitchDump variable and hence should be $null right?

But it keeps mapping the printer.

```
Switch ($SwitchDump = dsquery computer $OU_TO_SEARCH_IN|findstr $env:COMPUTERNAME | Out-String)
{
    $SwitchDump -ne $null {Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$PrintServer\$DesiredPrinter}
}
```

Or am I just barking up the wrong tree?
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the syntactical flaw in your switch condition, issue here is that `$SwitchDump` is the output from `Out-String` - it'll append a newline, so `$SwitchDump -ne $null` will _always_ be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SwitchDump = dsquery computer $OU_TO_SEARCH_IN | findstr $env:COMPUTERNAME | Out-String

Switch ($SwitchDump)
{
    {$_ -ne $null} {Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$PrintServer\$DesiredPrinter}
}
```

You need to use `$_` to represent the variable being tested by the Switch if you want to do anything beyond simple comparisons for values. You also need to make those comparisons a scriptblock by using `{ }`.

Comment: Wow thanks for your quick reply. This totally fixed my problem! I am using it like this now: {$_ -ne ""} {Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$PrintServer\$DesiredPrinter}   Works like a charme.

Comment: You're welcome! FYI you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick icon below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're *assigning* the `dsquery` to `$SwitchDump`... which will [almost] always return true `;-)`

You probably want to perform an equality check i.e.

```
Switch ($SwitchDump -eq dsquery computer $OU...
```

Also it looks like you have your `switch` syntax slightly off: https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html

```
$SwitchDump = dsquery computer $OU_TO_SEARCH_IN|findstr $env:COMPUTERNAME

if (-not $SwitchDump) {
    Write-Output "SwitchDump is empty"
}

switch ($SwitchDump) {
    $null    { Write-Host "SwitchDump = NULL"  ; break; }
    "value1" { Write-Host "SwitchDump = value1"; break; }
    "value2" { Write-Host "SwitchDump = value2"; break; }
    "value3" { Write-Host "SwitchDump = value3"; break; }
    default  { Write-Host "None of the above"  ; break; }
}
```